# How can I sign-in a user synchronously after user creation with firebase authentication in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to have users directly sign-in to my application after being created via Firebase authentication. I have a signUp method and a signIn method.

I have an authguard that returns access denied when calling the signIn method after the user is created.

My signUp method looks like this:

```
  // Sign up with email/password
async signUp(email, password) {
  return this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      this.signIn(email, password);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

My signIn method looks like this:

```
// Sign in with email/password
async signIn(email, password) {
  // sign user into firebase auth but not into the application
  return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      this.router.navigate(['auth']);
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error.message);
    });
}
```

Here is my authguard method:

```js
  canActivate(next, state): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => !!user),
      tap(loggedIn => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
          console.log('access denied');
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: I should add that the user is created succesfully, I can call each method individually and they work fine. I just am not sure how to chain these methods together.